# Is set-user-id bit set?

Tags: c++, c, unix, suid

I'm going to write a code which will extensively execute other programs. I don't want it to have root privileges if someone set a set-user-id bit(and root is an owner). So I'm going to drop privileges at startup.

My question is:
How can I understand from within the program whether it run in `set-user-id` mode?

Comment: You can simply decide to do `setuid(getuid());` which will do nothing if the program is not SUID and will reset the permissions if it is SUID.  You might still want to check for `getuid() == 0` (which means root is running the program).

Comment: Do you mean has your program been set with `setuid` or the other programs that your program will call are `setuid`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare result of `getuid()` and `geteuid()` [library calls](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man2/getuid.2.html).

If `geteuid()` returns 0 (root), but `getuid()` returns not 0, you can say that suid is active.